# Convert video to animated GIF on iOS

Tags: ios, animated-gif

I want to convert a video file taken with the camera (.mp4) and convert it to an animated GIF image.

I looked up the Apple Docs and there doesn't seem to be any built-in function for this.

How should I approach this task?

Comment: Why do you want to use GIF? It produces huge image files with a very limited color palette!

Comment: Why would iOS provide you with a way to convert mp4 to gif ? That would just create overhead and would bloat up your app. Use a dedicated video editing app (After Effects and the like...) to convert it to an image sequence.

Comment: @jtbandes, I am aware of the drawbacks of .GIF but the current project requires it for the web side.

Comment: @the_critic, I am talking about hundred of user provided videos. Editing each one in Ae, wouldn't be the most optimized solution :)

Comment: @pixthecoder Oh, did not think about that, sorry... Unfortunately, I can't help you then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in API for that. I released a library that converts video files to animated GIF images while giving enough flexibility to tweak settings such as frame rate, frame duration, size, etc.

The library is called [NSGIF](http://github.com/nsrare/nsgif). You can find it here: http://github.com/NSRare/NSGIF

This is the simplest way to convert a video to a GIF:

```
[NSGIF optimalGIFfromURL:url loopCount:0 completion:^(NSURL *GifURL) {
    NSLog(@"Finished generating GIF: %@", GifURL);
}];
```

Using the `optimalGIFfromURL` method, automatically generates the GIF based on the optimal settings. There is also room for way more flexibility. Check out the repo for more samples.

Comment: Looks great. Will check it out!

Comment: @JAck In fact this is the bug of iOS, and it fixed now. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17142

Answer (score 7):

You can do it in Some Step
1-
Calculate the required Frame

```
CMTime vid_length = asset.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(vid_length);
int required_frames_count = seconds * 12.5; //You can set according
```

to u

```
int64_t step = vid_length.value / required_frames_count;
int value = 0;
```

2-
Make Gif File Setting Property

```
destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path],
                                                                        kUTTypeGIF,
                                                                        required_frames_count,
                                                                        NULL);

   frameProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0.8] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime]
                                                                forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];


    gifProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount]
                                                              forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];
```

Step 3
Generate Frame from Video Asset AVAssetImageGenerator

```
 for (int i = 0; i < required_frames_count; i++) {

        AVAssetImageGenerator *image_generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
        image_generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
        image_generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
        image_generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

        image_generator.maximumSize = CGSizeMake(wd, ht);    //to get an unscaled image or define a bounding box of 640px, aspect ratio remains

        CMTime time = CMTimeMake(value, vid_length.timescale);
        CGImageRef image_ref = [image_generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
        UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image_ref];


        [self mergeFrameForGif:thumb];


        CGImageRelease(image_ref);
        value += step;


    }
    NSLog(@"Over all Size of Image(bytes):%ld",t);


    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (CFDictionaryRef)gifProperties);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
    CFRelease(destination);
    NSLog(@"animated GIF file created at %@", path);
```

Step 4 
Add Frame in Gif file

```
- (void)mergeFrameForGif:(UIImage*)pic1
{
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, pic1.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    pic1=nil;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated for Swift 5.1**

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import PhotosUI
import MobileCoreServices

func makeGIF(asset: AVAsset, destionationURL: URL, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {


let duration = asset.duration

let vid_length : CMTime = duration

let seconds : Double = CMTimeGetSeconds(vid_length)

let tracks = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)

let fps = tracks.first?.nominalFrameRate ?? 1.0

let required_frames_count : Int = Int(seconds * Double(fps)) // You can set according

let step : Int64 = vid_length.value / Int64(required_frames_count)

var value : CMTimeValue = CMTimeValue.init(0.0)

let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(destionationURL as CFURL, kUTTypeGIF, required_frames_count, nil)

let gifProperties : CFDictionary = [ kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary : [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount : 0] ] as CFDictionary

for _ in 0 ..< required_frames_count {
    
    let image_generator : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator.init(asset: asset)
    
    image_generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = CMTime.zero
    image_generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = CMTime.zero
    image_generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    
    // to get an unscaled image or define a bounding box of 640px, aspect ratio remains
    
    image_generator.maximumSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    
    let time : CMTime = CMTime(value: value, timescale: vid_length.timescale)
    
    do {
        
        let image_ref : CGImage = try image_generator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        
        let thumb : UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: image_ref)
        
        
        mergeFrameForGif(frame: thumb, destination: destination!)
        
        value = value + step
        
    } catch {
        
        //
        
    }
    
}

//print("Overall Size of Image(bytes): \(t)")


CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination!, gifProperties)
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination!)

print("animated GIF file created at \(destionationURL)")
    
}


func mergeFrameForGif(frame: UIImage, destination: CGImageDestination) {


let frameProperties : CFDictionary = [ kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary : [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime : 0.8] ] as CFDictionary

CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, frame.cgImage!, frameProperties)


}
```